# facebook App ID not found after adding firebase auth swift

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook

Recently added firebase to my swift project, prior to this the login had worked but now the app works and loads but when I click my login button, it crashes and I get an error saying the facebook app id could not be found even though it's in the Info.plist file. I added FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled and set it to NO as per the docs to disable swizzle but it doesn't work. After debugging I'm noticing that my app delegate for facebook is never called. Been stuck on this for a while and every fix I've found online doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.###</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb###</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>####</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>#####</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>AlmaAmor</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>GIDClientID</key>
    <string>#########.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(
            _ application: UIApplication,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
        ) -> Bool {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            // Initialize Facebook SDK
            FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                application,
                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
            )
            return true
        }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
=        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
        return true
    } }

class GoogleAppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      // Pass device token to auth
      Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)

      // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
      // ...
    }
}
```

and the relevant code for my login view:

```
struct FBLog: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var logged: Bool
    @Binding var email: String
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> FBLog.Coordinator {
        return FBLog.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> FBLoginButton{
        let button = FBLoginButton()
        
        button.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        
        button.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: Context){
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate{
        
        var parent : FBLog
        
        init(parent1: FBLog){
            parent = parent1
        }
        
        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            parent.logged = false
            parent.email = ""
        }
        
        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?){
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            
            if !(result!.isCancelled) {
                #Some code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then I just call FBLog on my screen to display the button.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, big stuck here! Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is how FBLog is called:

```
struct SignUpView: View {
@State var logged = false
@State var creatingAccount = false
@State var email: String = ""
@State var creationError = false
@State var logged_in_with = ""
@StateObject private var store = UserStore()
let dummyError = CreationError.basic

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if (logged == true) {
            if (creatingAccount) {
                CreateAccountView()
            } else {
                MainPage()
            }
        } else {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Get Started").bold()
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer() // Push the GoogleSignInButton to the center horizontally
                        GoogleSignInButton(action: handleSignInButton)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.77, height: geometry.size.height * 0.025)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: geometry.size.width * 0.04, leading: geometry.size.width * 0.04, bottom: geometry.size.width * 0.04, trailing: geometry.size.width * 0.04))
                            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.20))
                            .cornerRadius(geometry.size.width * 0.5)
                            .overlay(
                                VStack(spacing: geometry.size.width * 0.04) {
                                    // Your content inside the GoogleSignInButton, centered vertically
                                }
                            )
                        Spacer() // Push the GoogleSignInButton to the center horizontally
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer() // Push the FBLog to the center horizontally
                        FBLog(logged: $logged, email: $email)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.7, height: geometry.size.height * 0.025)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: geometry.size.width * 0.04, leading: geometry.size.width * 0.04, bottom: geometry.size.width * 0.04, trailing: geometry.size.width * 0.04))
                            .background(Color.blue) // Replace with your desired background color
                            .cornerRadius(geometry.size.width * 0.04)
                            .overlay(
                                VStack(spacing: geometry.size.width * 0.04) {
                                    // Your content inside the FBLog, centered vertically
                                }
                            )
                        Spacer() // Push the FBLog to the center horizontally
                    }
                    Spacer()

                }
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .green, .red]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .alert(isPresented: $creationError, error: dummyError) { error in
                    // If you want buttons other than OK, add here
                } message: { error in
                    if let message = error.errorMessage {
                        Text(message)
                    }
                }
                                }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
import SwiftUI
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FirebaseAuth


@main
struct BlahApp: App {
    @StateObject private var store = UserStore()
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(GoogleAppDelegate.self) var googleAppDelegate
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(FirebaseAppDelegate.self) var firebaseAppDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Landing()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is a little confusing - the normal code that's used to [authenticate to Facebook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login) appears to be missing. I would expect a call to `func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!` if you want to use Firebase Authentication with Facebook. Perhaps I am mis-reading the question and the code?

Comment: Thank you! The code you're referring to is under my Coordinator class and is instead called loginbutton, it should have the same functionality @Jay

Comment: Great. So when you add a breakpoint in the code at the `if error != nil` line and then run the code, what happens when you click the loginButton? Does that code execute? If so, as you step through the code line by line, on which line does it do something unexpected?

Comment: It never hits that code, I followed the documentation even more closely and still could not get it to hit the loginButton method, no matter what I try it doesn't seem to reach there.

Comment: In that case this issue is unrelated to Firebase. The button is simply not wired up to call that function. That could be because the delegate is not set up properly or possibly not instantiated elsewhere. We don't know what `LoginButtonDelegate` is as well so that could be the issue. Is that defined via a protocol or something else? How is `FBLog` being called. As you can see there's lots of code we're not seeing. Is `loginButton` supposed to log the user in? You're going to need to dig into the code to do some troubleshooting

Comment: The reason I think it's linked to Firebase is because prior to its addition (with no code changes made to FBLog or its related classes and structs) it worked fine. I will edit the post to show how it's called

Comment: My assumption based on your above comments is that when the button is clicked, the code within the function that's called does not execute. That would indicate the button click does not call the code at all. Just guesswork here.

Comment: Yeah that's right, you could be right in that I might have not set up the delegate correctly but all the code pertaining to the issue should now be posted, LoginButtonDelegate is just a protocol the Coordinator must use to serve as a delegate for FBSDKLoginButton. I've tried my hand (unsuccessfully) at fixing the issue so if you have any fixes you potentially see they'd be appreciated!

Comment: As per my first comment, I am not seeing a `FBSDKLoginButton` in the code and am not seeing `FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult` as a result of that. I am not seeing the required UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor and don't know if app delegate swizzling is disabled. Go back and take a look at the [Facebook Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login#implement_facebook_login) instructions as what's presented there definitely works. Yours may too but we need to start somewhere.

Comment: Both FBSDKLoginButton and FBSDKLoginManagerResult seem to have been changed, FBSDKLoginButton is now FBLoginButton which I have in my code (in the FBLog makeuiview) and FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult is just LoginManagerLoginResult which I also have in my Coordinator class loginButton function. I've disabled swizzling, this can be verified in the posted Info.plist where I set FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to false. I've posted the app delegate but can post where it is used in the entry point. The Facebook Auth code does work on a blank project but once Firebase is added it no longer does!

Comment: I've just added the entry point

Comment: Huh - the documentation clearly calls out FBSDKLoginButton but I see you point in that appears to be depreciated so the docs are incorrect. What's not clear if it's a 1-1 replacement.

Comment: Given the guides I followed online, I would presume so.. what worries more so is that it had worked previously, at a loss on how to fix this..